# i have integrate AutocompleteSupportFragment on map fagment .when im click on place search .app is crashed

Tags: google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

i have integrate AutocompleteSupportFragment on map fagment .when im click on place search .app is crashed.its giving *error.java.lang.NullPointerException: Place Fields must be set.*

```
 AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
          getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_frag);

        if (autocompleteFragment != null) {
            autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));
        }

        if (autocompleteFragment != null) {
            autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull Place place) {
                    // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
       Toast.makeText(getContext(),place.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Status status) {
                    // TODO: Handle the error.
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Have you found the solution? I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the Google developer Doc on this doesnt tell you the step you need to initialize Places (why would they include that...), but all you need to do is add the following snippet where you initialize the `autoCompleteFragment`variable.

```
    if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
        Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "YOUR_API_KEY);
    }
```

Cheers